# WCF services not working after .Net Framework upgrade from 3.5 to 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, upgrade

I am upgrading WCF services from .Net Framework 3.5 to .Net Framework 4.6.2.

I have tried upgrading two services out of many services. Both services work on my local IIS but do not work on the server after deployment.

The service returns wsdl information on the first call on browsing the svc but keeps on loading & loading if I try to browse the svc again. I have to start & stop the server iis to be able to make it return wsdl response again but the response is again only returned for the first call.

By successful response return the first time I only mean  that I am able to browse the service svc in my browser.

There are no errors, no exceptions, no help from trace logs or server iis logs.

Can anyone point out what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Have you checked that the server has 4.6.2 installed?

Comment: Yes, 4.6.2 is installed on the server. Its present under 'Add or remove programs'

Comment: Ok, and which .net framework is the web app defined to use in IIS?

Comment: We are pointing the AppPool to work with CLR version 4.0.

Comment: From a VisualStudio Developer command prompt, run `WcfTestClient.exe` and 'Add service' giving it your SVC's URL. See if that gives any clues, or lets you invoke any of the methods.

Comment: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://service.svc, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI:
http://service.svc Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://service.svc'. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized. HTTP GET Error URI: http://service.svc There was an error downloading 'http://service.svc'. The operation has timed out.

Comment: That error is fair enough - if it's an internet-facing service then it's a good idea to have the metadata switched off, to prevent hackers analysing your API; but I'm hoping that the server in question is just a "Test" server, so you can switch on the metadata to assist your diagnosis. If it's already switched on, then maybe that authentication error helps - I would certainly expect you to be seeing something in the Windows Event Log on the server for that. P.S. I'm not sure why all the mentions of "service.svc" in your comment have ended up as hyperlinks, because they don't look like URLs.

Comment: ...Please assure me that you typed in the full URL for the SVC, not just "service.svc". :)

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning that, yes I did type in the full url for the SVC, i had to write shorthand name because of the total words restrictions on comments.

Comment: @user9728592 a screenshot of IE taken from localhost would be helpfull. Also if you could paste your web.config.

Comment: Metadata is already switched on, i have resolved the authentication issue by enabling anonymous authentication. But still I am stuck with the infinite loading issue. I cannot share the web config as it is client code.